# Installing ggplot2 for R 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, r

I have R 3.6 installed from the [r-project.org repository](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/), as instructed in [this post from R Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/installation-of-r-3-5-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/). Now I would like to install the `ggplot2` package, but am not succeeding.

Usually I prefer to install everything as user packages, R works better that way. However, with this version the `isoband` package, on which `ggplot2` depends, fails to compile:

```
$ sudo R 

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘isoband’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/isoband_0.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1894070 bytes (1.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3031461 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘isoband’ ...
** package ‘isoband’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/testthat/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:79:0,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Rmath.h: In function ‘double R::pythag(double, double)’:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Rmath.h:222:57: error: ‘::Rf_pythag’ has not been declared
     inline double pythag(double a, double b) { return ::Rf_pythag(a, b); }
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/Rmath.h:222:57: note: suggested alternative: ‘pythag’
     inline double pythag(double a, double b) { return ::Rf_pythag(a, b); }
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~
                                                         pythag
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:177: recipe for target 'RcppExports.o' failed
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘isoband’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/isoband’
ERROR: dependency ‘isoband’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ggplot2’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpzfegOo/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("ggplot2") :
  installation of package ‘isoband’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("ggplot2") :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

The same [R Bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/installation-of-r-3-5-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/) suggests a PPA from Michael Rutter as a source of pre-compiled packages. However, this PPA seems to be installing packages of incompatible versions:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5
[...]

$ sudo apt-get update
[...]

$ R

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library("ggplot2")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
 package ‘scales’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
>
```

Would there be a different way of installing `ggplot2` with R 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before installing R 3.6 I removed the version installed from the universe, following the instructions in the [R Bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/installation-of-r-3-5-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/):

```
sudo apt purge r-base r-recommended r-cran-*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
```

However this is insufficient. It leaves behind a folder with the R packages compiled locally. This could be a bug with the `r-base` package, that even with `apt purge` is leaving assets behind:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
assertthat  desc      ggplot2    lifecycle     pkgload      purrr         rprojroot   tidyselect
backports   digest    glue       lubridate     plogr        R6            rstudioapi  timeDate
BH          dplyr     gower      magrittr      plyr         ranger        scales      utf8
callr       ellipsis  gtable     ModelMetrics  praise       RColorBrewer  SQUAREM     vctrs
caret       evaluate  ipred      munsell       prettyunits  Rcpp          stringi     viridisLite
cli         fansi     isoband    numDeriv      pROC         RcppEigen     stringr     withr
colorspace  farver    iterators  pillar        processx     recipes       testthat
crayon      foreach   labeling   pkgbuild      prodlim      reshape2      tibble
data.table  generics  lava       pkgconfig     ps           rlang         tidyr
```

Therefore, to completely remove the old R version, this folder must be deleted:

```
sudo rm -Rf /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
```

And then yes, a more recent version can be installed from r-project.org:

```
sudo apt install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

This way it is possible to install packages like `ggplot2` with the `install.packages` method:

```
R
[...]
> install.packages("ggplot2")
```